# Input fields collection value does not get selected on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have an app with `clients` and `invoices`,
When a user creates an `invoice` they need to associate it to a `client` which I am doing successfully with a `collection input field` in my `form`. I  added 'include_blank' to handle the case of a new user signing up that does not have any clients. This is where I ran into trouble.

After I added `:include_blank => "Select Client"` my edit form stopped selecting the associated client and instead now defaults to "Select client"

My forms input

```
<%= f.input_field :client_id, :collection => current_user.clients.order(created_at: :desc), selected: params[:client_id], :label_method => :client_name, :value_method => :id, :include_blank => "Select Client", class: "form-control" %>
```

Why is the `:include_blank` showing in the edit form where the `client_id` exists? How do I get the associated `client_id` to show?

My form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@client, @invoice] do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<% if @invoice.errors.any? %>
<ul>
  <% @invoice.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
 </ul>
<% end %>
    <...>
 <div class="row invoice-info">
  <div class="col-xs-2 invoice-col">
  Select Client
    <%= f.input_field :client_id, :collection => current_user.clients.order(created_at: :desc), selected: params[:client_id], :label_method => :client_name, :value_method => :id, :include_blank => "Select Client", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2 invoice-col">
    <%= link_to 'New Client', new_client_path(@client), class: "btn btn-danger" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be good to see more of the ERB around this line. Specifically what the `form_for` looks like. Though, it's likely something to do with `params[:client_id]`. Are you sure the `params` hash has that key when this ERB is being processed?

Comment: Yeah so if I remove `:include_blank => "Select Client"` everything works as expected. The correct client shows up in the `input field`

Comment: Are you seeing same result when you pass `:prompt => "Select Client"` instead of `include_blank`?

Comment: Yes same result with `:prompt => "Select Client"`

Comment: can you post the generated HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I removed `selected: params[:client_id]` and now it is working as expected with `:include_blank => "Select Client"`

`selected: params[:client_id]` was returning `nil` and it seems the form builder was capable of interpreting `:client_id` once `selected: params[:client_id]` was removed.